# Display Return Value in HTML

Tags: php, ip, backend, dom-manipulation

I have to create a tool like (whatsmyip.com) but with special filters or so, I have to implement this code into a html site but don't know how to echo the returned value in html..
Thanks for your help

```
    public function getClientIp() {
        if ($this->clientIp) {
            return $this->clientIp;
        }
        $ip_keys = ['HTTP_CLIENT_IP', 'HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR', 'HTTP_X_FORWARDED', 'HTTP_X_CLUSTER_CLIENT_IP', 'HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR', 'HTTP_FORWARDED', 'REMOTE_ADDR'];
        foreach ($ip_keys as $key) {
            if (isset($_SERVER[$key])) {
                foreach (explode(',', $_SERVER[$key]) as $ip) {
                    // trim for safety measures
                    $ip = trim($ip);
                    // attempt to validate IP
                    $filterOptions = FILTER_FLAG_IPV4 | FILTER_FLAG_IPV6 | FILTER_FLAG_NO_PRIV_RANGE | FILTER_FLAG_NO_RES_RANGE;
                    if (filter_var($ip, FILTER_VALIDATE_IP, $filterOptions) !== false) {
                        return $ip;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        $this->clientIp = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] ?: false;
        return $this->clientIp;
    }
```

i need somehing like this do display the ip

```
<h1>Was ist meine IP-Adresse?</h1>
<p>Hier sehen Sie, welche IP-Adresse Sie derzeit für Ihre Internetverbindung nutzen.</p>
<br /><br /><div style="background-color:lightgray; padding:10px;">{source}<span style="font-family: courier new, courier, monospace;">&lt;?php echo "Ihre IP-Adresse lautet: $clientIp" ?&gt;</span>{/source}
</div>
```

Comment: `echo getClientIp();`?? It's a bit unclear what the problem is - echoing things is pretty straightforward, as long as you're clear what it is you want to echo. In this case, you're returning the IP from the function, so echoing the result of the function would be logical. I feel like that's too obvious though, is there actually another problem? If so, you need to clarify your question.

Comment: @ADyson i need something like this https://pastebin.com/Ns1ZQQA0
At the bottom there is some text and here should the ip be displayed

Comment: Put any relevant info into your question please, not in other sites. But anyway `<script type="text/php">` isn't valid, it needs to be enclosed in standard `<?php ... ?>` brackets. And it would need the function definition as you've provided above. Once you've done that, then just insert the echo I suggested into the HTML wherever you want it (inside PHP tags, obviously).

Comment: @ADyson i tried <?php ... ?> but then it would just display my whole code as plain text and also i don't know how to echo the returned variable, is it a global one? or do i just need to call the function where i need the output and then the returned variable gets displayed?

Comment: `but then it would just display my whole code as plain text`...that suggests you don't have PHP installed and running in your webserver, and/or you're not using this within a .php file, and/or you're not accessing it via a `http://` URL.

Comment: `i don't know how to echo the returned variable`...you just echo it. Literally just echo it. Like I showed you. In my example, the result isn't even assigned to a variable, it's just immediately echoed. There is no actual variable. `do i just need to call the function where i need the output and then the returned variable gets displayed`...as long as you then echo it. Calling the function just executes the code within the function. What you do with the result of that is up to you. `echo`ing it is one of the options you have at that moment. I wonder if you need to go study some PHP basics.

Comment: P.S. You also need to amend the function itself a bit. See answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply need to echo the result of the function which returns the IP address:

```
echo getClientIp();
```

You also need to amend the function - I guess you took this code from somewhere else without really understanding it (which is [rarely a good idea](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult_programming)). It's clearly meant to be part of a class, hence the `public` and all the references to `$this`. I've changed it below so it will work as a standalone function.

Full example:

```
<?php

function getClientIp() {
    $ip_keys = ['HTTP_CLIENT_IP', 'HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR', 'HTTP_X_FORWARDED', 'HTTP_X_CLUSTER_CLIENT_IP', 'HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR', 'HTTP_FORWARDED', 'REMOTE_ADDR'];

    foreach ($ip_keys as $key) {
        if (isset($_SERVER[$key])) {
            foreach (explode(',', $_SERVER[$key]) as $ip) {
                // trim for safety measures
                $ip = trim($ip);
                // attempt to validate IP
                $filterOptions = FILTER_FLAG_IPV4 | FILTER_FLAG_IPV6 | FILTER_FLAG_NO_PRIV_RANGE | FILTER_FLAG_NO_RES_RANGE;
                 if (filter_var($ip, FILTER_VALIDATE_IP, $filterOptions) !== false) {
                    return $ip;
                 }
             }
        }
    }

    $clientIp = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] ?: false;
    return $clientIp;
}
?>

<h1>Was ist meine IP-Adresse?</h1>
<p>Hier sehen Sie, welche IP-Adresse Sie derzeit für Ihre Internetverbindung nutzen.</p>
<br /><br />
<div style="background-color:lightgray; padding:10px;">
  {source}
    <span style="font-family: courier new, courier, monospace;">
      Ihre IP-Adresse lautet: <?php echo getClientIp();?>
    </span>
  {source}
</div>
```